# Using a query inside RowMapper

Tags: java, sql, spring, resultset, jdbctemplate

In java i would do something like below to iterate the `resultset` and form the query,

```
public Map<String, List<MODEL>> fun(){
Map<String, List<MODEL>> map = new TreeMap<String, List<MODEL>>();      
        LinkedHashSet<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<String>();

            String sql = "select distinct(column) from table where conditions orderby column ";
            ResultSet rslt = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            while (rslt.next()) {
                al.add(rslt.getString(1));
            }
            for (String s : al) {           
                List<MODEL> list = new ArrayList<MODEL>();
                String sql2 = "select * from table where column="+s;
                ResultSet rslt2 = stmt.executeQuery(sql2);
                while (rslt2.next()) {
                    MODEL obj = new MODEL();
                    // set values to setters from resultset
                    list.add(obj);
                }
                map.put(s, list);
            }
            return map;
            }
```

*the reason why i have used the separate query is , i am adding the distinct values to the map key and their corresponding values(as List) to the values of the map .**NOTE** (In the result it has duplicate values of the **column1**)  , But i need to store them as map key and hence making it as unique .
also i need all its associated values so populating a list*

How can i achieve the same functionality using `JdbcTemplate` ,

Thanks in advance

Comment: What you are doing is not a good idea to do with regular JDBC code! The performance suffers from repeatedly querying the database. You'd be better off using a join query and then extracting the relevant data. It goes without saying that to transfer your JDBC code to Spring using RowMapper like you propose, would be even worse. A RowMapper should be a dumb object that creates DTOs. Nothing more

Comment: yes i know , but the requirement has the above chance alone . And i am sure that the first query will contain only 3 to 4 results . so that wont cause performance issue . is there a way to do it using spring jdbc?

Comment: Even consider that i am adding my result set to the set and am iterating it again

Comment: I strongly suggest merging both queries into one query `select * from table where column in (select distinct(column) from table)` you can then use a `RowMapper` to map the actual results. Instead of 5 queryies you are now doing one and have simplified your code.

Comment: so is it possible to get the 2nd query result if i merge them `(select distinct(column) from table)` . what i need is a map with key as 2nd part of the query you formed and the values of the first part of the query

Comment: One observation: Your query lets be attacked by SQL Injection. Is a bad practice has something attached in the query `+rs.getString(1)` use the `setParameter` method(s) instead. JdbcTemplate has support to do that.

Comment: @ManuelJordan thanks will change to prepared statements

Comment: you could make the rowmapper a spring-managed bean, and inject a dao into it. it would be nasty but definitely possible.

Comment: @NathanHughes thanks for your comment . any similar examples or so questions . i will edit my question make it a bit clear

Comment: @NathanHughes i have edited my post , please check it now . it is the exact thing i wish do with `jdbc template` . is it possible ?

Answer (score 2):

As stated by multiple people your solution isn't efficient although it might work you are basically falling into the trap of the [1+N select problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-issue). 1 query to retrieve some id and next for each id another query (hence 1+N select).

It would be better to just write a single query which retrieves everything in one go. Looking at your code you have the following 2 queries which, by the looks of it, operate on the same table.

```
String sql1 = "select distinct(column) from table where conditions orderby column ";
String sql2 = "select * from table where column="+s
```

Now you can either make the first query a subselect for the second query

```
String sql = "select * from table where column in (select distinct(column) from table where conditions) order by column";
```

However, again from the looks of it, it would also be possible (or maybe even easier) to just put the where clause in your second query.

```
String sql = "select * from table where conditions order by column";
```

You will now, possibly, get for your key (in the `Map`) get multiple values. You can do two things either use a `ResultSetExtractor` loop over the results yourself or use a `RowCallbackHandler` which does the iteration for you.

What you need to do is just iterate of the results (or let the `JdbcTemplate` do that for you) for you key column check the `Map` if a `List` is already there. If it is add a row if it isn't first create the `List` and add it to the result `Map`.

```
public Map<String, List<MODEL>> fun(){
    final Map<String, List<MODEL>> map = new TreeMap<String, List<MODEL>>();      

    String sql = "select * from table where conditions order by column";
    getJdbcTemplate().query(sql, new RowCallbackHandler() {
        public void processRow(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {
            String key = rs.getString("column");
            List rows = map.get(key);
            if (rows == null) {
                rows = new new ArrayList<MODEL>();
                map.put(key, rows);
            }
             MODEL obj = new MODEL();
            // set values to setters from resultset
            rows.add(obj);
        }, "arguments"); 
    return map;
}
```

Another solution, which would only work if the 'column' is also part of the `MODEL` class. That way you could use a `RowMapper` and get a `List` of all `MODEL` objects and do the partitioning afterwards. You could use Google Guava to make it a little easier to do that or if you are on Java 8 you could use the new streams api for that.

Answer (score 1):

As @geoand said, the best thing (whether in straight JDBC code or using JDBCTemplate) would be to do a single query with a Join.

If, however, as you mentioned in the comments, you are absolutely certain that the result set from the first query will *always* be small (doubtful), then you could store the values retrieved from the first query in a list, and then do a second query with an "in" clause, using the list as a parameter. This would result in two queries.

In any case, you really don't want to do a separate query for each item returned from the first query, as this will be quite slow, even for small numbers of items. But, if you feel that you **must**, then store the results of the first query in a list, and then issue another query for each item in the list.

TLDR; No, JDBCTemplate does not provide a mechanism for doing what you want, mostly because it's generally considered to be a canonical example of a programming anti-pattern.

Comment: Well actually `JdbcTemplate` does provide such a mechanism by using a `ResultSetExtractor`. Which you could use to iterate yourself and execute a query again, not that I would advice it but alas.

Comment: @M.Deinum the final result i need is something like this `Map<Result of 1st query, list of 2nd query values >` And the reason i needed to i may have duplicates of 1st query result . but i need the single value

Comment: Judging from the code you posted you cannot have duplicates as you used a distinct.

Comment: ok . but is it possible to get the values of the 2nd part of the query also there may be many entries for the `select distinct(column) from table` , the reason i use distinct is i get the unique values for the key . And in the second query i use it to get the all values associated  with `distinct(column)`

Comment: @M.Deinum  i have edited my post , please check it now . it is the exact thing i wish do with `jdbc template` . is it possible ?